# Pandas slow to merge and convert to datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two columns of data in a DataFrame containing a date and a time. Both start as strings. I want them to end up merged as a single column in datetime format.

The head of the DataFrame is:

```py
    Date          variable   value
0   '04/10/2020'    '00:30'  81.310
1   '05/10/2020'    '00:30'  121.245
2   '06/10/2020'    '00:30'  77.020
3   '07/10/2020'    '00:30'  100.705
4   '08/10/2020'    '00:30'  114.370
```

They are in a DF called `df_flattened` and has about 20k rows and the code I am currently using is:

```py
df_flattened['DateTime'] = df_flattened.apply(lambda x: x['Date'] + ' ' + x['variable'], axis=1)
df_flattened['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df_flattened['DateTime'])
```

However, this takes about 2.6s to run and the dataset is going to get a lot bigger in the future. Can anyone suggest a fast way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `+` for join columns instead `apply`:

```
df_flattened['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df_flattened['Date'] + ' ' + df_flattened['variable'])
```

Also is possible specify format of joined datetimes:

```
df_flattened['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df_flattened['Date'] + ' ' + df_flattened['variable'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
```

Performance for 20k rows:

```
#20k rows
df_flattened = pd.concat([df_flattened] * 4000, ignore_index=True)


In [44]: %%timeit
    ...: df_flattened['DateTime'] = df_flattened.apply(lambda x: x['Date'] + ' ' + x['variable'], axis=1)
    ...: df_flattened['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df_flattened['DateTime'])
    ...: 
    ...: 
325 ms ± 26.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [45]: %timeit df_flattened['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df_flattened['Date'] + ' ' + df_flattened['variable'])
11.9 ms ± 1.51 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [46]: %timeit df_flattened['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df_flattened['Date'] + ' ' + df_flattened['variable'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
9.55 ms ± 96.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: @GalacticPonderer... Removing the unnecessary apply with axis=1 and using know format will drastically improve performance.  +1

Comment: It did indeed. Dropped it down to 0.9s. Thanks